# Can I visualize views of Athena using Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

Is it possible to make charts of views of Athena using Quicksight?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Here is a blog post that includes a view used in QuickSight that I found when I searched for ["quicksight athena view"](https://www.google.com/search?q=quicksight+athena+view): [Analyze and visualize nested JSON data with Amazon Athena and Amazon QuickSight](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-and-visualize-nested-json-data-with-amazon-athena-and-amazon-quicksight/)